# ES6 Arrow Functions () vs _

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, parameters, arrow-functions

I tried looking this up and did not find an answer. Is there any reason to use `_` over `()` when passing in 0 parameters in an arrow function? Just asking out of curiosity.

```
// ...(() => {}) vs (_ => {})
```

Comment: I dont think `_` is 0 parameters. It means there is an argument but you are ignoring it.

Comment: Very weird....saves a character I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences are:

- `_` creates an identifier for the `_` variable. (In rare circumstances, this may be confusing if one is using a library which assigns to `window._`, like underscore.js)
- Using `_` means that parentheses aren't needed. (In contrast, declaring a function with zero arguments requires an empty parameter list with `()`) Some like saving on a character by using `_` instead.

(One could have, equivalently, used any other argument name like `z` which then goes unused - but the convention for an unused variable is to use `_`)

If one isn't using a library that assigns to `window._`, then the `_` parameter won't shadow it, so both options work just fine. Feel free to choose whichever strikes your fancy.

Note that a common linting rule forbids the declaration of unused parameters, and will require `()` instead of `_`.

Comment: Interesting, so it's basically just an unused placeholder parameter. Thanks for the info!